# Can parent parameters take children parameters?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parameters

```
function cached(fn){

  // Create an object to store the results returned after each function execution.

  const cache = Object.create(null);



  // Returns the wrapped function

  return function cachedFn (str) {



    // If the cache is not hit, the function will be executed

    if ( !cache[str] ) {

        let result = fn(str);



        // Store the result of the function execution in the cache

        cache[str] = result;

    }



    return cache[str]

  }

}
```

From my understanding !cache[str] checks if the cache variable is an array containing the str parameter in it. Which makes sense since an array is an object in js. It's essentially a weird way of defining an array. The fn(str)is throwing the rest of my understanding of the code. Is it any example of inheritance or something else ?

Comment: There are no arrays in the code you posted. The `cache` variable has a reference to an object as its value.

Comment: `!cache[str]` checks to see if a value has been cached with the property name held in the "str" parameter.

Comment: "*the cache variable is an array*" - nope. `cache = Object.create(null)`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parents, children, inheritance or parameters. `o[p]` is just a [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on an object.

Comment: Can someone explain the fn(str) side of the equation im starting to understand the object cache reference and it simply taking the str property name

Answer (score 0):

This is a (tremendously simplified) example of something called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)